# Error in doInBackground()

Tags: android, json, runtimeexception

I am trying to take values from 5 URL`s here the code:

```
 new JsonTask().execute(urlPosts, urlPhotos, urlComments, urlComments, urlAlbums, urlUsers);
```

but, I am getting stuck in this class:

```
protected JSONObject[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        JSONObject[] jsonObjects = new JSONObject[4];

        jsonObjects[0] = getPosts();
        jsonObjects[1] = getPhotos();
        jsonObjects[2] = getComments();
        jsonObjects[3] = getAlbums();
        jsonObjects[4] = getUsers();

        return jsonObjects;
    }
```

The Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.marcellosouza.saberproject, PID: 12105
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
                  at com.example.marcellosouza.saberproject.view.activity.MainPageBlogActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainPageBlogActivity.java:102)
                  at com.example.marcellosouza.saberproject.view.activity.MainPageBlogActivity$JsonTask.doInBackground(MainPageBlogActivity.java:80)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Why am i getting this error?How can i solve it?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am i getting this error?

You are clearly told why - just read whole stacktrace carefully:

> Caused by: java.lang.**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**: length=4; index=4

It even tells you that your array is 4 element in size (length=4) but you are trying to reach outside of it -> `index=4`. As array indices start at `0`, then `4` means 5th element, hence the crash.

The stacktrace then tells you where the faulty code is:

> com.example.marcellosouza.saberproject.view.activity.MainPageBlogActivity
>                  $JsonTask.doInBackground(**MainPageBlogActivity.java:102**)

What you do wrong is - you declare 4 element array:

```
    JSONObject[] jsonObjects = new JSONObject[4];
```

but later you try to stuff 5 in it:

```
    jsonObjects[0] = getPosts();
    jsonObjects[1] = getPhotos();
    jsonObjects[2] = getComments();
    jsonObjects[3] = getAlbums();
    jsonObjects[4] = getUsers();
```

That's not gonna work. Fix `jsonObjects` creation or use i.e. `ArrayList` to avoid fixed size arrays.